# How do I move the parent element when swiping over an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a slider that detects swipes via the touchmove event and moves the content accordingly.  However when there is an iframe in the content, and I slide my finger over the iframe, the page won't move because the touchmove event is intercepted by the iframe itself, not the parent page.  Thus the parent div doesn't move.

This iframe also needs to remain clickable since it is an ad so I can't just cover it with another div that has a higher z-index.

What can I do in Javascript to bubble the touchmove event up to the parent?  They are on the same domain.  Any help would be appreciated!

The slider I am using is this - http://dezignhero.github.io/swiper.js/  (which works fine when there are no iframes in the pages)

```
var Swiper = function(selector, options) {

/*------- Globals -------*/

var viewportWidth = 0,
    frameWidth = 0,
    animating = false,
    numSlides = 0,
    limitEnd = 0,
    goTo = 0,
    currentSlide = 0,
    orientation = 0;

// Swiping
var swipe = {
    started : false,
    startX : 0,
    endX : 0,
    at : 0,
    strength : 0
};

// Settings
var settings = {
    ease : 0.3,
    swipeMin : 40,
    preventAdvance : false,
    container : '.container',
    frame : '.page',
    frameWidth : false,  // accepts a number in pixels
    controls : '.control',
    clickEvent : 'click',
    updateEvent : 'update',
    controlsOnly : false,
};

/*------- Handles -------*/

var el = selector,
    $parent = $(el),
    $container, $controls, $frame, $prevCtrl, $nextCtrl;

/*------- Methods -------*/

var init = function(options) {
    // Exit if element doesn't exist
    if ( $(el).length == 0 ) return;

    // Merge settings
    settings = $.extend(settings, options || {});

    // Initialize handles
    $container = $(settings.container, el);
    $controls = $(settings.controls, el);
    $frame = $(settings.frame, el);

    // Assign Ids to frames
    $frame.each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('data-id', i);
        numSlides++;
    });

    // Add initial class
    $($frame.selector+'[data-id=0]', el).addClass('current');

    // Set Dimensions
    resize();

    // Setup CSS
    $container.css({
        '-webkit-transition' : 'all '+settings.ease+'s ease-out',
        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate3d(0,0,0)',  // Performance optimization, put onto own layer for faster start
        'left' : 0
    });

    // Monitoring controls if they exist
    if ( $controls.length > 0 ) {
        // Determine whether or not to use click event
        if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
            settings.clickEvent = 'touchstart';
        }

        // Create handlers
        $prevCtrl = $(settings.controls+'[data-action=prev]');
        $nextCtrl = $(settings.controls+'[data-action=next]');

        // Bind behavior
        $controls.on(settings.clickEvent, function(){
            var self = $(this),
                action = self.attr('data-action');

            // Ensure action defined
            if ( typeof action == 'undefined' ) return;

            if ( action == 'next' && currentSlide < numSlides - 1 ) {
                goTo = currentSlide + 1;
            } else if ( action == 'prev' && currentSlide > 0 ) {
                goTo = currentSlide - 1;
            }

            // Move container
            jumpTo(goTo);
        });
    }

    // Display controls correctly
    if ( settings.preventAdvance ) {
        disableSliding();
    } else {
        updateControls();
    }

    // Swiping
    if ( !settings.controlsOnly ) {
        $container[0].addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { touchStart(e); }, false);
        $container[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { touchMove(e); }, false);
        $container[0].addEventListener('touchend', function(e) { touchEnd(e); }, false);
        // Desktop
        $container[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { touchStart(e); }, false);
        $container[0].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) { if (e.which==1) { touchMove(e); } }, false);
        $container[0].addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) { touchEnd(e); }, false);
    }

    // Prevent anchor tags from getting in the way
    $('a', el).on('touchstart click', function(){
        return swipe.started ? false : true;
    });

    // Prevent image dragging on getting in the way
    $('img', el).on('dragstart', function(){
        return false;
    });

    // Check if Android
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;

    // Orientation Change
    var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
        orientationEvent = (supportsOrientationChange && !isAndroid) ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

    // Listener for orientation changes
    window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
        // Prevent 'fake' orientation calls
        if ( orientation != window.orientation ) {
            orientation = window.orientation;
            resize(function(){
                jumpTo(currentSlide);
            });
        }
    }, false);
},

resize = function(callback){
    viewportWidth = $parent.width();
    frameWidth = ( settings.frameWidth ) ? settings.frameWidth : viewportWidth;

    // Apply new sizes
    $frame.width(frameWidth);
    $container.width(frameWidth*numSlides);

    // Set end limit
    limitEnd = settings.frameWidth ? viewportWidth/frameWidth : numSlides;

    // callback
    if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) {
        callback();
    }
},

touchStart = function(e) {
    swipe.at = getPosition();  // for touch move
    // Get start point
    swipe.startX = e.touches ? e.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
    swipe.startY = e.touches ? e.touches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
    swipe.endX = swipe.startX;  // prevent click swiping when touchMove doesn't fire
},

touchEnd = function(e) {
    swipe.started = false;

    // Nullify event
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( animating ) return;

    var moved = swipe.endX - swipe.startX,
        threshold = frameWidth / 3;

    goTo = currentSlide;

    // Figure out closest slide
    if ( Math.abs(moved) > threshold || swipe.strength > settings.swipeMin ) {
        if ( moved > 0 && currentSlide > 0 ) {
            goTo--;
        } else if ( moved < 0 && currentSlide < limitEnd-1 ) {
            goTo++;
        }
    }

    // Jump to closest        
    jumpTo(goTo);
},

touchMove = function(e) {
    if ( !$parent.hasClass('disabled') ) {
        swipe.started = true;
        var touchX = e.touches ? e.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
            touchY = e.touches ? e.touches[0].pageY : e.pageY,
            dX = touchX - swipe.startX,
            dY = touchY - swipe.startY;

        swipe.strength = Math.abs(touchX - swipe.endX);
        swipe.endX = touchX;

        // Escape if motion wrong
        if ( Math.abs(dX) < Math.abs(dY) ) return;

        e.preventDefault();

        // Always run this so that hit the ends
        animate(swipe.at+dX, false);
    }
},

getPosition = function() {
    // Get current point and Stay there
    var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle($container[0], null),
        transform = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);

    // Return position based on direction
    return transform.m41;
},

animate = function(scrollTo, ease) {
    // Momentum Effect or Not
    $container[0].style.webkitTransition = ( ease ) ? 'all '+settings.ease+'s ease-out' : 'none';
    $container[0].style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+scrollTo+'px,0,0)';

    // Allow animating again
    if ( ease ) {
        animating = true;
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            animating = false;
        }, settings.ease*1000);
    }
},

jumpTo = function(num, ease) {
    // Keep within range
    if ( num >= 0 && num < limitEnd ) {

        // Animate
        var hasEase = ( typeof ease !== 'undefined' ) ? ease : true;
        animate(-num*frameWidth, hasEase);

        // If new slide
        if ( num != currentSlide ) {
            // Update current slide
            currentSlide = num;

            // Update current slide
            $frame.removeClass('current');
            $($frame.selector+'[data-id='+currentSlide+']').addClass('current');

            // Update parent to trigger update event and new slide
            $parent.trigger(settings.updateEvent, [ currentSlide, Math.floor(limitEnd) ]);

            // Control Buttons
            updateControls();

            // Disable Again
            if ( settings.preventAdvance ) {
                disableSliding();
            }
        }
    }
},

updateControls = function() {
    // Only run if controls exist
    if ( $controls.length == 0 ) return;

    if ( currentSlide >= 0 && currentSlide < limitEnd ) {
        $controls.show();
        if ( currentSlide == 0 ) {
            $prevCtrl.hide();
        } else if ( currentSlide == limitEnd-1 ) {
            $nextCtrl.hide();
        }   
    } else {
        $controls.hide();
    }
},

disableSliding = function() {
    // Hide Controls
    $('.control', el).hide();
    // Add disabled flag
    $parent.addClass('disabled');
},

enableSliding = function() {
    // Enable control buttons
    updateControls();
    // Remove disabled flag
    $parent.removeClass('disabled');
};

// Initialize the object
init(options);

return {

    element : $parent,

    jumpTo : jumpTo,

    swiping : function() {
        return swipe.started;
    },

    disableSliding : disableSliding,

    enableSliding : enableSliding,

    status : function() {
        return {
            'current' : currentSlide+1,
            'total' : numSlides
        }
    },

    next : function() {
        jumpTo(currentSlide+1);
    },

    prev : function() {
        jumpTo(currentSlide-1);  
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the iframe swallows touch events. So on the area that you are swiping if there is any iframe, you wont be able to swipe. The only solution I know, is to cover the iframe with a transparent div and dispatch any click events to the iframe. This way touchmove event will be enabled on the iframe.

I have created a basic jquery plugin to do that here.
https://gist.github.com/agaase/6971953

Usage

```
$(selector).coverIframes();
```

This will cover any iframes inside $(selector) with a transparent div and transfer any click events.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but you can use:

```
iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: That's not enough. In this way swipe works, but click to start video doesn't work.